# Abstract Nav Drawer Android

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to abstract my Navigation Drawer to streamline my Android app but I'm running into some issues. The Nav Drawer simply doesn't respond to touches, I can't figure out why.

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : NavActivity() {
/** ON CREATE **/
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
       main_seekbar_price!!.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this)
       mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout) // Variable in superclass
...
```

NavDrawer.kt

```
abstract class NavActivity : BaseActivity() {

/** Variables **/
lateinit var mDrawerLayout: DrawerLayout


/** ON CREATE **/
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nav)

    // Set Nav Drawer listener
    nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener { menuItem ->
        Log.d("NAV", "nav selected listener header")
        menuItem.isChecked = true
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers()
        navMenuSwitch(menuItem)
        true
    }

    // Set Nav Footer listener
    nav_footer.setNavigationItemSelectedListener { menuItem ->
        Log.d("NAV", "nav selected listener footer")
        menuItem.isChecked = false
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers()
        navMenuSwitch(menuItem)
        true
    }
}
...
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    ...

    </FrameLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/activity_nav" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

activity_nav.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_header"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header">

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_footer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_footer">
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

I thought it has something to do with assigning mDrawerLayout in the child class but that didn't fix anything. It never calls the listeners though, no matter how much you click it it won't even print Logs in that listener.

Any help is welcome as I can't figure this out for the life of me, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Four things happen, in this order, when your `MainActivity`'s `onCreate()` is called:

1. `MainActivity`'s content view is set by inflating `activity_nav.xml`.
2. The `nav_view` and `nav_footer` Kotlin variables are assigned by searching the content view for them. ([Kotlin does this for you](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html#view-binding), so it's easy to forget that it's happening.)
3. Listeners are attached to the `nav_view` and `nav_footer` views.
4. `MainActivity`'s content view is set again, this time by inflating `activity_main.xml`. (The `include` tag inside `activity_main.xml` tells the framework that it should inflate another copy of `activity_nav.xml` as part of the process.) The old content view is overwritten.

So by the time `MainActivity.onCreate()` finishes, the views with listeners attached are gone. One way to fix the problem would be to delete the line `setContentView(R.layout.activity_nav)` from `NavActivity.onCreate()` and to move the rest into an `initNavDrawerListeners()` method that's called from `MainActivity.onCreate()`.